# ftp connexion trough haproxy

Tags: ftp, haproxy

At the moment I have two servers under centos 7.

- 10.10.104.200 = Loadbalencer with Haproxy
- 10.10.105.100 = web server

I want the clients to enter their ftp (ex Filezilla) 10.10.104.200 and be redirected automatically to the server 10.10.105.100. I still have not found a way that works well.

Here is my current configuration of haproxy.cfg:

```
global
  log /dev/log local0
  log /dev/log local1 notice
  chroot /var/lib/haproxy
  stats timeout 30s
  user haproxy
  group haproxy
  daemon

defaults
  log global
  mode http
  option httplog
  option tcplog
  retries 3
  maxconn 10000
  option redispatch
  option dontlognull
  timeout connect 5000
  timeout client 50000
  timeout server 50000

frontend http_front
  bind *:80
  default_backend http_back

backend http_back
  balance roundrobin
  server serveurBack 10.10.105.100:80 check

listen stats
  bind *:8181
  stats enable
  stats uri /
  stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
  stats auth ****:*****
```

Comment: Please edit your question and write more exactly what *exactly* are the clients doing with the Filezilla (?). Port 80 is for http, not ftp.

Comment: Hello,

Customers use Filezilla to connect to their FTP account. They use port 21 with a username and password.

Answer (score 1):

Jean,

As with the previous answer, you don't have the correct port.
But you will also need to understand if you want Passive FTP support (almost certainly).

And If you want PASV support you will need to restrict the high ports on the server:

```
listen FTPVIP
bind 192.168.1.123:21 transparent
    bind 192.168.1.123:10000-10020 transparent
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    balance leastconn
    stick on src
    stick-table type ip size 10240k expire 30m
    server WinFTPServer2016FTP1 192.168.1.110 check port 21 inter 10s rise 2 fall 2
    server WinFTPServer2016FTP2 192.168.1.111 check port 21 inter 10s rise 2 fall 2
```

You can find more detailed instructions for [FTP with HAProxy here](https://www.loadbalancer.org/blog/how-to-load-balance-microsoft-windows-ftp-server-with-haproxy/):