# How to forward traffic from HaProxy to an IIS FTP server?

Tags: iis, ftp, haproxy

I'm trying to steer FTP traffic through HaProxy to an IIS FTP server. I've also tried to setup a FileZilla FTP server, but the issues were similar - passive mode does not work.

This is my `haproxy.cfg`

```
listen FTP
  mode tcp
  bind <HAPROXY_SERVER_IP>:21 transparent
  bind <HAPROXY_SERVER_IP>:50000-55000 transparent
  server ftp01 <IIS_FTP_SERVER_IP>
```

Passive ports config on IIS:

[image]

I've looked at a similar question - [ftp connexion trough haproxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/961131/ftp-connexion-trough-haproxy) - however the proposed answer (based on [this blog post](https://www.loadbalancer.org/blog/how-to-load-balance-microsoft-windows-ftp-server-with-haproxy/)) did not work for me. FTP login works but directory listing command (`ls`) errors with:

```
425 Cannot open data connection.
```

---

I've also looked at [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/PiBa-NL/d826e0d6b35bbe4a5fc3) while looking for options to forward client IP to the FTP server. As FTP connections are TCP-based, I can't use the **(1)** `X-Forwarded-For` HTTP header. AFAIK, FileZilla and IIS FTP service do not support **(2)** proxyprotocol. This only leaves option **(3)**:

```
source 0.0.0.0 usesrc clientip
```

which looks [quite complex to configure](https://www.loadbalancer.org/blog/configure-haproxy-with-tproxy-kernel-for-full-transparent-proxy/)!

---

What am I missing here? Surely this is not such a difficult task!

---

### My systems

#### HaProxy VM

OS: `Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS` 
HaProxy version: `HAProxy version 2.4.14-1ppa1~focal 2022/02/25`

#### FTP server VM

OS: Windows Server 2019 
IIS version: `10.0.17763.1`

The VMs are connected to the same local network.

## Update

I'm including client and server logs for the session that failed

### Client

```
# Note: h1, h2, h3, h4 make up the <IIS_FTP_SERVER_IP>

ftp -p <HAPROXY_SERVER_IP>
Connected to <HAPROXY_SERVER_IP>.
220 Microsoft FTP Service
Name (<HAPROXY_SERVER_IP>:<LOCAL_PC_USERNAME>): <FTP_USERNAME>
331 Password required
Password:
230 User logged in.
Remote system type is Windows_NT.
ftp> ls
227 Entering Passive Mode (h1,h2,h3,h4,195,80).
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection.
425 Cannot open data connection.
ftp> bye
221 Goodbye.
```

### IIS FTP Server

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2022-07-12 23:01:15
#Fields: date time c-ip cs-username s-ip s-port cs-method cs-uri-stem sc-status sc-win32-status sc-substatus x-session x-fullpath
2022-07-12 23:01:15 <HAPROXY_SERVER_IP> - <IIS_FTP_SERVER_IP> 21 ControlChannelOpened - - 0 0 a46aa445-e3be-46ba-9da2-3f5520e3c419 -
2022-07-12 23:01:29 <HAPROXY_SERVER_IP> - <IIS_FTP_SERVER_IP> 21 USER <FTP_USERNAME> 331 0 0 a46aa445-e3be-46ba-9da2-3f5520e3c419 -
2022-07-12 23:01:52 <HAPROXY_SERVER_IP> <IIS_SERVER_MACHINE_NAME>\<FTP_USERNAME> <IIS_FTP_SERVER_IP> 21 PASS *** 230 0 0 a46aa445-e3be-46ba-9da2-3f5520e3c419 /
2022-07-12 23:01:52 <HAPROXY_SERVER_IP> <IIS_SERVER_MACHINE_NAME>\<FTP_USERNAME> <IIS_FTP_SERVER_IP> 21 SYST - 215 0 0 a46aa445-e3be-46ba-9da2-3f5520e3c419 -
2022-07-12 23:01:54 <HAPROXY_SERVER_IP> <IIS_SERVER_MACHINE_NAME>\<FTP_USERNAME> <IIS_FTP_SERVER_IP> 21 PASV - 227 0 0 a46aa445-e3be-46ba-9da2-3f5520e3c419 -
2022-07-12 23:01:54 <FTP_CLIENT_IP> <IIS_SERVER_MACHINE_NAME>\<FTP_USERNAME> <IIS_FTP_SERVER_IP> 50000 DataChannelOpened - - 0 0 a46aa445-e3be-46ba-9da2-3f5520e3c419 -
2022-07-12 23:01:54 <FTP_CLIENT_IP> <IIS_SERVER_MACHINE_NAME>\<FTP_USERNAME> <IIS_FTP_SERVER_IP> 50000 DataChannelClosed - - 1236 38 a46aa445-e3be-46ba-9da2-3f5520e3c419 -
2022-07-12 23:01:54 <HAPROXY_SERVER_IP> <IIS_SERVER_MACHINE_NAME>\<FTP_USERNAME> <IIS_FTP_SERVER_IP> 21 LIST - 425 1236 38 a46aa445-e3be-46ba-9da2-3f5520e3c419 /
2022-07-12 23:02:06 <HAPROXY_SERVER_IP> <IIS_SERVER_MACHINE_NAME>\<FTP_USERNAME> <IIS_FTP_SERVER_IP> 21 QUIT - 221 0 0 a46aa445-e3be-46ba-9da2-3f5520e3c419 -
2022-07-12 23:02:06 <HAPROXY_SERVER_IP> <IIS_SERVER_MACHINE_NAME>\<FTP_USERNAME> <IIS_FTP_SERVER_IP> 21 ControlChannelClosed - - 0 0 a46aa445-e3be-46ba-9da2-3f5520e3c419 -
```

Comment: Can you check and post what  PORT response your FTP client receives after requesting a passive connection with the PASV control word?

Comment: After setting port range on IIS machine, did you restart its FTP service or simply reboot it? The settings on that page won't take effect immediately. You need a tool like Wireshark to analyze the actual FTP packets so as to tell what goes wrong, HaProxy or the FTP server behind.

Comment: @LexLi I've restarted both the site and the service. Hopefully, I won't have to resort to WireShark.

Comment: @Rob Thank you for your answer, I'm still processing it. I hope my edit answers your question.

Comment: `h1, h2, h3, h4 make up the <IIS_FTP_SERVER_IP>` - that’s the root of your problem. That should be the HAProxy servers IP-address

Comment: I got it working by also setting the **External IP Address of Firewall** to the IIS FTP site (before it was only configured globally, for the entire IIS server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FTP is a crappy protocol that requires two connections:

1. For passive FTP that is initially one connection, the control connection. That connection is made by the client, typically to the default port, TCP 21.
2. To actually transfer data (and getting a directory listing is a data transfer) the client needs to make a second TCP connection, the data connection.

When the FTP client requests a passive ftp connection with the `PASV` control word,  the FTP server selects a "random available ephemeral", non-default port and announces that port with the PORT response.

The `PORT` response typically contains 6 octets, eg `PORT h1,h2,h3,h4,p1,p2` where `h1.h2.h3.h4` is the server's IPv4 IP-address and the TCP port number is `(p1*256) + p2` i.e. `xxx,x,xxx,xxx,196,107` represents port `(196 * 256) + 107 = 50283`

To play nicely with firewalls, rather than allowing the FTP server to select  just any "random available ephemeral" port for the data connection, an administrator usually establishes a fixed port range.

It looks like you did fix that port range, but did you also open the required firewall ports?

Now the second thing is that the `PORT` response contains the IP-address of the server. You will need to ensure that the FTP client receives there the IP-address of the HAProxy server that they are connecting to and not the IP-address of the IIS server.

Your screenshot shows that IIS provides such an option, the "External IP-address of the Firewall"  allows the administrator to adjust the IP-address that will be used in the PORT response. Rather than the actual IP-address bound to the server that custom IP-address will be used in `PORT` responses. That is often the solution for problems caused by port forwarding, hence the name, but that is also the solution for your HAProxy.

Alternatively the device doing the port forwarding (in this case HAProxy) will need to rewrite the IP-address in the PORT response with it's own.
AFAIK HAProxy does not offer a standard way of doing that for you.

To check: what is the PORT response your FTP client receives?